# Converting a string to a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, iteration

I am trying to convert string into Dictionary in Python. I have tried the following but getting the error
'dict' object is not callable. Please help me solve this problem.

```
l=[]
str='Vijay=23,Ganesh=20,Lakshmi=19,Nikhil=22'
for x in str.split(','):
     y=x.split('=')
     l.append(y)
d=dict(l)
for k in d:
   print('{:1s}---{:1s}'.format(k,d[k]))
```

Comment: You're getting error because you probably overrode `dict` with something (like you did with `str`). It's a bad practice

Comment: Your code actually works, if you execute it in a new console/kernel, but as @JL0PD said, don't 'rename' basic python methods/type, like `dict` or `str`

Answer (score 0):

```
s = 'Vijay=23,Ganesh=20,Lakshmi=19,Nikhil=22'

dct = {n: a for n, a in (p.split("=") for p in s.split(","))} #Credits to JL0PD
print(dct)
#{'Vijay': '23', 'Ganesh': '20', 'Lakshmi': '19', 'Nikhil': '22'}
```

Comment: solution with single split per pair `{n: a for n, a in (p.split("=") for p in s.split(","))}`

Comment: @Andreas can u please explain this i am not able to understand

Comment: @ChayanMehrotra it is called dictionary comprehension, you can find tutorials for it. It might be better if you first look into them. Essentially you put all the loops into a single line. But be aware the code you posted originally would work as well. Just be carefull not to rename standard names like str or dict

Answer (score 0):

```
l=[]
str='Vijay=23,Ganesh=20,Lakshmi=19,Nikhil=22'
for x in str.split(','):
     y=x.split('=')
     l.append(y)
result = {}
for item in l:
    result[item[0]] = item[1]
print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try.

**Step1**
Iterate through `['Vijay=23', 'Ganesh=20', 'Lakshmi=19', 'Nikhil=22']`

**Step2**
Split every person by `=`. `['Nikhil', '22']`

**Step3**
Add the first element to the dict as a key and the age to the dict as a value

---

```
peopleDict = {people.split('=')[0]:int(people.split('=')[1]) for people in string.split(',')}
```

**output**

```
{'Vijay': 23, 'Ganesh': 20, 'Lakshmi': 19, 'Nikhil': 22}
```

#Note1: Make sure you do not name your variable `str` or `int`, `input` etc. These are all methods created by python, don't overide them.

#Note2: my output turns all the ages into integers just in case you need to manipulate them later on in your code.

Comment: You missed a terrible mistake he had... he override the `str` class

Answer (score 0):

You override the reserved word `str`.
In python the word `str` is the name of the class string.

When you wrote `str = 'Vijay=23,Ganesh=20,Lakshmi=19,Nikhil=22'`,
you changed the class str to be 'Vijay=23,Ganesh=20,Lakshmi=19,Nikhil=22'

run this code:

```
l = []
string = 'Vijay=23,Ganesh=20,Lakshmi=19,Nikhil=22'
for x in string.split(','):
    y = x.split('=')
    l.append(y)
d = dict(l)
for k in d:
   print('{:1s}---{:1s}'.format(k,d[k]))
```

#### Same code but follows [PEP8 rules](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

```
pars_list = []
row_data = 'Vijay=23,Ganesh=20,Lakshmi=19,Nikhil=22'
for i in row_data.split(','):
    pars_list.append(i.split('='))

data = dict(l)
for k in data.keys():
    print('{:1s}---{:1s}'.format(k, data[k]))
```